# what is sprintf("%!ld")?

Tags: c, visual-c++, printf

I've stumbled accross:

```
sprintf(buffer, "%!ld ", date);
```

I understand the ld is for long integer, but what is the purpose of the `!` ? I can't find any reference on this, and the output seems similar to the classical `%ld` for me

edit : apparently on my system it appends to the variable the string `+to_date('01/01/1904','DD/MM/YYYY'))` ... this is indeed used to query database so it transforms the date into an actual oracle date (I think).
Now I'll try to see if this is a special sprintf and where it comes from

Comment: Where did you find that code?

Comment: Have you tried it? What does it do? Why can't you assume it's just a wrong piece of code?

Comment: What system does this work on? gcc only complains.

Comment: Could this be a vendor specific extension? What compiler are you using? Never heard of this...

Comment: the compiler is the one with VS 2008
I have the exact following :
sprintf(buffer, " from %s H1 where " [line break here]
"H1.JOUR = %!ld ", name.c_str(), date);

Comment: I'll try to actually debug the result and see what is written, but it apparently works as intended since it's everywhere in the code

Comment: In VS2008 it's not a documented flag for formatting

Comment: ok I edited my post, I think the question can be closed since now it's clearly something specific to me only

Comment: Had a look in output.c in the CRT source of VS. It's not a supported flag at all and I can't imagine how %!ld can format a DATE! :O I feel the smell of a macro...

Comment: @Adriano : I'm apparently actually calling an in-house _sprintf_ function, so there is no way you can help me further.
thanks to everyone

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's an invalid format string.

I think most printf implementations, when getting an invalid format string, treat the `%` as a literal, not a special character. So it will print `%!ld`.

If it works like `%ld` for you, then, as some comments say, perhaps it's a non-standard extension of your platform.

Comment: Or maybe the implementation of (s)printf on his platform ignores invalid format modifiers, i.e. it interprets `%!ld` as `%ld` which would explain why it works for him but isn't documented anywhere.

Comment: @sepp2k, Indeed this seems the most likely case.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know, this won't be valid for printf - or would just be ignored. The only situation I know of, where you use something like `%!` is FormatMessage on Windows, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa908810.aspx

Comment: In this case, `%!ld!` makes sense, not `%!ld`. But maybe it's the source of confusion.

Answer (score 0):

I think it will print %!ld as this is not a valid format specifier in C.